# What is the best way to manage styles that depend on props?

Tags: react-native

I have a basic component like this:

```js
const BasicComponent = (props) => {
    return <Text style={styles.text}>Hi!</Text>
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text: {
        fontSize: 20
    }
})
```

I want to be able to take a prop that changes the color of the text. I could either change the return to

```js
<Text style={[styles.text, {color: props.color}]}>Hi!</Text>
```

or move `const styles` inside the `BasicComponent` function and set `color: props.color` there, which in my opinion looks cleaner.

I have never seen the `const styles` inside the function/class before. But it works just fine. Is one method preferred over the other? Which is best practice? Or is it up to individual opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is helpful when it comes to handling multiple themes, what I usually do is use a function for the StyleSheet, something like this:

[image: demo]

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, Button, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const Demo = ({ theme = 'light', toggleTheme }) => (
  <View style={styles.container(theme)}>
    <Text style={styles.title(theme)}>{theme}</Text>
    <Button title="Change Theme" onPress={toggleTheme} />
  </View>
);

export default () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light');

  const toggleTheme = () => setTheme(theme === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light');

  return <Demo theme={theme} toggleTheme={toggleTheme} />;
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: theme => ({
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: theme === 'light' ? '#fff' : '#000',
  }),
  title: theme => ({
    fontSize: 25,
    color: theme === 'light' ? '#000' : '#fff',
  }),
});
```

See a working snack here https://snack.expo.io/@abranhe/61e11d

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea like this hope it helps you

```
const BasicComponent = (props) => {
    const {color} = props
    return <Text style={styles.text(color)}>Hi!</Text>
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text: (color = "black") => ({
        fontSize: 20,
        color: color
    })
})
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by an explanation.